# Android Text view height changes in dynamic

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having problem setting a `TextView` height dynamically. My `xml` file is

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/rateUpdateTime"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:text="@string/update_time"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_weight=".48"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#5FB6CB"

        />
```

In this `TextView` I'm setting different messages based on the action happening in my activity. So I need to set height as `wrap_content` dynamically. Also I'm using different controllers in `LinearLayout`. This `TextView` belongs within this single `LinearLayout`. Please any one help me to set `TextView` Height = `LinearLayout` dynamically.

Comment: you should use `fill_parent` as you are using `layout_weight` in a `Linear_Layout` child and if you need to have multiple lines then you need to add `android:singleLine="false"`

Comment: try to change in your .java file!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the values of Layout params in the .java code may solve this. Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) for documentation.